# react-navigation V6: what's the difference between replace and navigate

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

From the [react-navigation/native V6 documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/)
`navigation.replace` replaces the current route with a new one
whereas `navigation.navigate` goes to another screen and figures out the action it needs to take to do it

Can you please explain me what's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Navigate

> navigate - go to another screen, figures out the action it needs to
> take to do it

Navigate will go to the screen, but the action it takes to go there will depend on the type of navigator.

- For bottom Tab it will simply replace the route with the new one to
  navigate and pressing back in android at least will by default
  navigate to first screen in navigator.
- For Stack, navigate will push the new route into the current stack. The previous components in the route will still be mounted. Only popping them will unmount them. In a stack, going back will simply pop.

### Replace

> replace - replace the current route with a new one

Replace will simply replace the current route with a new one. What this means in a stack navigator is, that the current component will be unmounted and the component from new route will be mounted. Which is a different behaviour from what navigate would've done (push)

TLDR: Navigate takes best course of action, Replace only works in some navigators, with specifically unmounting current and mounting new.

Comment: Is there a situation where you would prefer replace over navigate?

Comment: It's helpful for back navigation. If you use replace, back navigation will not navigate to previous view. This could be used for authentication or direct flows in your app

Comment: This makes sense. I have a splash screen, where it makes sense to replace rather than navigate and leave the splash screen in the navigation flow.

Comment: @user1666858 if you have the app on background on "view A for id 1", and receive a push notification that should redirect you to "View A" but for id 2... navigator.navigate won't load the view for id2, but .replace will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I just do

```
    this.props.navigation.reset({
          index: 0,
          routes: [
            {
              name: 'SelectNewsFeed',
            },
          ],
        });
```